# retrieving NSString from array in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsarray

I have an array which contains description of a route on map. I got this array by parsing JSON. My arrays contains string in this format:

```
    "<b>Sri Krishna Nagar Rd</b> \U306b\U5411\U304b\U3063\U3066<b>\U5317\U6771</b>\U306b\U9032\U3080",


"\U53f3\U6298\U3057\U3066\U305d\U306e\U307e\U307e <b>Sri Krishna Nagar Rd</b> \U3092\U9032\U3080",


        "\U5927\U304d\U304f\U5de6\U65b9\U5411\U306b\U66f2\U304c\U308a\U305d\U306e\U307e\U307e <b>Bailey Rd/<wbr/>NH 30</b> \U3092\U9032\U3080<div class=\"\">\U305d\U306e\U307e\U307e NH 30 \U3092\U9032\U3080</div><div class=\"google_note\">\n<b landmarkid=\"0x39ed57bfe47253b7:0x779c8bf48892f269\" class=\"dir-landmark\">Petrol Bunk</b>\U3092\U901a\U904e\U3059\U308b<div class=\"dirseg-sub\">\Uff083.9&nbsp;km \U5148\U3001\U53f3\U624b\Uff09</div>\n</div>",
```

Now I want to get name of places from this array like `Sri Krishna Nagar Rd` , `NH 30 Petrol Bunk`. First two should give `Sri Krishna Nagar Rd` and last on should give `NH 30 Petrol 
Bunk`
How can I get result like this.Any help would be appreciated. Thanx In Advance.

Again, suppose I have string in this format...`"\U5de6\U6298\U3059\U308b"` which don't have ny place name.How will i handle this scenarios.

Comment: Do you know exactly in which position you placed your place name? I mean have any specific order?

Comment: I have one more doubt the above string is a content of a single index of an array?

Comment: Hello surya Kant, are you getting now?

Comment: Thnx All for ur +ve reponses. Now, m getting that place name.

Comment: I have updated, please check. but finally if you get empty string in "your place string" then handle it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    You can get like below:


  NSString *strName=[yourArray objectAtIndex:index];

    NSString *yourPlaceString=[[strName componentsSeparatedByString:@"<b>"] objectAtIndex:1];
    yourPlaceString=[[yourPlaceString componentsSeparatedByString:@"</b>"] objectAtIndex:0];

    you can get all places like this.
```

Comment: please get proper solution within 2 mins.

Comment: Again, I got a problem.This won't work if the route doesn't have name of the places for reference. App crashes in that scenarios. Also, if I use ur code like this..it gives names Like.."Sri Krishna Nagar Rd</b> \U306b\U5411\U304b\U3063\U3066",  I only want Sri Krishna Nagar Rd.I have edited my question, please have a look that...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should check if you don't have any other cleaner API available for the service you query this data. If the service returns such garbage in its JSON response, that shouldn't be your responsability to clean up that mess: the service should return some text that is more usable if it is a real clean API.

Next, if you really don't have any other choice and really need to clean this text, you have two options:

- If the text is XHTML (I mean real XHTML, conforming to the XML standard) you may use an `NSXMLParser` to filter out any tags and only keep the text from your string. This may be a bit too much for this anyway so I don't really recommand it.
- You can use **regular expressions**. If you are developping for iOS4.0+ you can use the `NSRegularExpression`class for this purpose. The tricky part is to get the right regex (can help you with that if needed)
- You can **use the `NSScanner` class** (which is available in iOS since 2.0 IIRC) to scan characters in you string and parse it. This is probably easier to understand and the way to go if you are not a regex expert, so I recommand this approach

For example if you choose the `NSScanner`solution, you can scan your string for characters in the alphanumeric character set, to scan letters and digits and accumulate it *(you may also add ponctuation characters to your `NSCharacterSet`you are using if needed)*. You will have the `NSScanner` to stop when it encounter characters such as the unicode characters \Uxxxx or like `<` and `>`. When you encounter `<` you can then ask the `NSScanner` to ignore the characters up to the next `>`, then start to scan the alphanumeric characters again and accumulating... and so on until the end of the string.

---

Finally, if you really find a pattern in the response string you are receiving, like if your place names is always between the first `<b>` and `</b>` pair (but you have to be sure of that), you can handle it other ways, like:

- splitting your string using the `<b>` text as the separator (e.g. `componentsSeparatedByString`)
- or asking the `rangeOfString` for the string `<b>` and then for string `</b>` and once you have their position, only extract `substringWithRange` from your original string to extract only the place name *(using `rangeOfString` will be faster that `componentsSeparatedByString` because it will stop on the first occurrence found)*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an encoding problem - can you change the encoding of the source or target to a different format. I had similar issues with German ö ä ü characters when UTF-8 was turned off....

Comment: I see no encoding problem there. The received text/response contains unicode characters, but that's not an encoding problem (on the contrary using the \Uxxxx notation avoids encoding confusion)

Comment: That's right, but if those characters where easily readable they might be much easier to understand and as I assume be identified as simple keywords to just skip during parsing...